# What software allows non-parametric repeated-measures multi-way Anova?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, software

A previous user asked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/a-non-parametric-repeated-measures-multi-way-anova-in-r) specifically for R.  I'd like to know what, if any, other software can do this.

Answer (score 1):

This question was updated with a link to the previous question, at which point I realized that my response originally posted here pointing to the ez package in R was better left at the previous question.