# Is it wrong to jitter before performing Wilcoxon test?

Tags: r, nonparametric, ties

I wrote a script tests the data using the `wilcox.test`, but when I got the results, all the p-values where equal to 1.
I read in some websites that you could use jitter before testing the data (to avoid ties as they said), I did this and now I have an acceptable result. 
Is it wrong to do this?

```
test<- function(column,datacol){
    library(ggplot2)
t=read.table("data.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
uni=unique(c(t$V9))
    for (xp in uni) { 
          for(yp in uni) {
            testx <- subset(t, V9==xp)
            testy <- subset(t, V9==yp)
            zz <- wilcox.test(testx[[datacol]],jitter(testy[[datacol]]))
            p.value <- zz$p.value
          }
        }
}
```

---

This is the output of `dput(head(t))`

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0.268912,
0.314681, 0.347078, 0.286945, 
0.39562, 0.282182), V2 = c(0.158921, 0.210526, 0.262024, 0.322006, 
0.133417, 0.283025), V3 = c(0.214082, 0.166895, 0.132547, 0.147361, 
0.09174, 0.169093), V4 = c(0.358085, 0.307898, 0.258352, 0.243688, 
0.379224, 0.2657), V5= c(-0.142223, 0.010895, 0.14655, 
0.08152, 0.02116, 0.030083), V6 = c(0.096408, -0.091896,

-0.331229, -0.446603, -0.088493, -0.262037), V7` = c(1.680946, 
1.649559, 1.534401, 1.130529, 3.441356, 1.211815), V8 = c("NC_000834",  "NC_000844",
"NC_000845", "NC_000846", "NC_000857",
"NC_000860" ), V9 = c("Chordata",
"Arthropoda", "Chordata", "Chordata", 
"Arthropoda", "Chordata"), V10 =
c("???:???", "Diplostraca", 
"???:???", "Rheiformes", "Diptera",
"Salmoniformes"), V11 = c("???:???",
"Branchiopoda", "Mammalia", "Aves",
"Insecta", "Actinopterygii" )), .Names
= c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6",  "V7",
"V8", "V9", "V10",
"V11"), row.names = c(NA,  6L),
class = "data.frame")
```

The data is very large, and that's the thread I started and they told me it might be wrong to do this

**Note** This question comes from tex.SE:
[generating PDFcontain R output inside latex table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15013/generating-pdfcontain-r-output-inside-latex-table)

Comment: You don't tell us what your data is, but I'd be very suspicious of any procedure that adds random noise to data and then runs a statistical test on it.  In addition, are you sure your code does what you think it does?  My reading is that despite your loop, it will return a single p.value - that of x=y={lastvaluof}(uni)

Comment: @Andrie: thanks for your help, but that's not the complete code, that's a part of the function that calculate the wilcox test , and the code producing different values of p-value for each (xp,yp) ,that's a link of a part of my data , you can view it and check if i can do this, thanks in advance .                    http://www.mediafire.com/?mnj26kp4bv5lcr5

Comment: I would be very suspicious of links to data that require redirecting to other links, especially when R provides the very useful `dput()` function that eliminates any need for doing that. Please provide a reproducible example to receive assistance.

Comment: cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554037/is-it-wrong-to-jitter-before-performing-wilcox-test

Comment: @weblover When I suggested (on tex.SE) to ask your stats question here, I wasn't aware you already asked on SO. Please, delete one of your two posts (probably on SO, since this is a stats question).

Comment: hello , i think someone did migrate the question from SO to here , but now there is 2 question with the same title , you will have to delete one of them , and btw when using dput(t,"test.txt") on the data i have, the result was not readble nicely , is there any option to use with it?

Comment: @weblover - use `dput()` on the R object in your working environment which looks like `t` above. the output isn't intended for human consumption - it is intended for the R interpreter to recreate the object `t` exactly as it exists in your working environment.

Comment: @Chase: i edited the question and added the output of dput(head(t)) , thanks

Comment: @Chase : what do i have like alternative to this test?? or how should prevent ties without adding jitter???

Comment: There are no ties in the subset of the data you posted here, and as the data goes to six decimal places, it seems odd that you would have any ties at all.  How much data do you have and how many ties are there? Something like this `sapply(d, function(x) sum(duplicated(x)))` will give you the number of ties in each column of a data set `d`.

Answer (score 7):

There's a thread on the R-help list about this; see for example: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e8/help/09/12/9200.html

The first suggestion there is to repeat the test a large of number of times with different jittering and then combine the p-values to get an overall p-value, either by taking an average or a maximum.  They also suggest that a straightforward permutation test could be used instead (of the two, that's what I'd prefer).  See the question [Which permutation test implementation in R to use instead of t-tests (paired and non-paired)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6127/3601) for some examples of permutation tests.

Elsewhere in that thread, Greg Snow writes:
Adding random noise to data in order to avoid a warning is like removing the batteries from a smoke detector to silence it rather than investigating the what is causing the alarm to go off. 
(See http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e8/help/09/12/9195.html )

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i did not got the point , what should i do now ? change the test , or adjust the data based on something , and what's this something???

Comment: I'll summarize the page I linked to.

Answer (score 4):

(disclaimer: I didn't check the code, my answer is just based on your description)

I have the feeling that what you want to do is a **really bad idea**. Wilcoxon is a resampling (or randomization) test for ranks. That is, it takes the rank of the values and compares these ranks to all possible permutations of the ranks (see e.g., [here](http://www2.statistics.com/resources/glossary/w/wmwutest.php)).

So, as you realized, ties are pretty bad as you don't get ranks out of them. However, adding random noise (jitter) to your data will transform all ranks, so that they have random ranks! That is, it distorts your data severely.

Therefore: **It is wrong to do so**.

Comment: thnx for you answer , but what should i do in this case ??

Answer (score 3):

You've asked several people what you should do now.  In my view, what you should do now is accept that the proper p-value here is 1.000.  Your groups don't differ.

Comment: hello , is it rational to accept this ?? because all groups and subgroups when compared together , gives the same p-value , that's not logical because in each case i'm testing 1 variable e.g : test("Ph",V1) , soo p-value should not be the same for all . any ideas ??

Comment: Sure, it could be rational.  A p-value of 1 means that the two groups are as close to the same as possible.  If you've got almost all ties, this could be true.

Comment: @Aaron @Web These data (V1 through V7) are not tied.  An error must have been made somewhere in obtaining p-values of 1.  I get a lot of p-values of 0.036 when comparing them with the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

Comment: The OP only posted the first few rows of the data; apparently there must be ties further on, though that does seem unlikely as the data goes to six decimal places.  So yes, it does seem that there might be an error in the analysis, though not exactly the one you point out.