# Is there a non-parametric form of a 3-way ANOVA?

Tags: regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, nonparametric

I am currently in the process of writing a publication about the home range of cat shark species in South Africa. However, I am currently struggling with how to create an interaction model of shark species, maturity level and sex, and their effect on the average travel distance within the study region. I was hoping to gain a test statistic (non-parametric) and p value for each category (e.g. mature male leopard shark, mature female leopard shark, immature male leopard shark, etc.). To do this I have tried a gaussian GLM though this does not give me the output I'm looking for since I'm using 3 fixed factors and no covariates. I've also tried a Scheirer-Ray-Hare test, though this only allows for 2 factors. Does anyone have any ideas of what test I could potentially use?

Comment: Why do you state that the GLM does not give you want you want? I suspect you wanted to fit it with all the two-way interactions and a three-way but that does not mean you need covariates.

Comment: I am very confused by the output on R as it gives me 2 three-way interactions (male mature leopard sharks, and male mature pyjama sharks). If it only gave one interaction model, or every interaction model this wouldn't be an issue. There isn't anything wrong with the code as I have checked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have data for every combination of sex, maturity and species?

Comment: I do yes, I've removed a shark species from the model because there wasn't enough data

Comment: You can specify the model formula so that it omits the 3-way interactions in your GLM, if those aren't relevant to your study. Your choice of parametric versus other types of models (e.g., proportional odds) should be based on which type of model best matches the characteristics of your data.

Comment: The purpose of your analysis is not clear. What do you mean by "test statistic and p value for each category"? What hypotheses do you want to test? Do you want to investigate how the three predictors interact?

Comment: I am looking to test the interactive effects of species, sex and maturity on the average travel distance of recaptured sharks. Species has three levels, sex of course has two and maturity also has two. I hope that makes things clearer. The test statistic and p value would have been derived from a GLM if that was to be used, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: Do you want, for each unique combination of the three factors, to extract from the model the average travel distance and its standard error?

Comment: No I've already got those numbers, I'm just looking for a non-parametric statistical test that will determine if there's a significant difference when taking the three combinations in to account

Answer (score 7):

ANOVA, even a 3-way ANOVA, is a special case of linear regression.

For one-way ANOVA, the typical "nonparametric" flavor is the Kruskal-Wallis test, so it seems like you would want some kind of 3-way Kruskal-Wallis test.

[Much as ANOVA is a special case of linear regression, the Kruskal-Wallis test is a special case of proportional odds ordinal logistic regression.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19573/247274)

Consequently, there is a sense in which the nonparametric flavor of 3-way ANOVA is a proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model on the variables, their two-way interactions, and their three-way interactions, much as the parametric flavor of 3-way ANOVA would be linear regression on the variables, their two-way interactions, and their 3-way interactions.

This is the first I've heard of the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test, but [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheirer%E2%80%93Ray%E2%80%93Hare_test) makes it sound like it can handle any number of factors, not just two, so perhaps your inability to include three factors is a software issue. Additionally, the Wikipedia article makes it sound like the Scheirer-Ray-Hare test is another special case of the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you, I've also had a look at the ordinal logistics regression though I'm not sure how this would work as my dependent variable is continuous and not ordinal. Is there a different kind I should consider?

Comment: @TomJohnson All ordinal means is that your data can be ordered, which (presumably) yours can be. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/130217/247274) post and rebuttal are worth reading.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I will give it a go

Answer (score 2):

The exchange in comments now makes this clearer. The OP has three species of shark, two level of maturity, and two sexes of shark. This forms a $3\times2\times2$ design. There will be 2 degrees of freedom for species, 1 for sex, 1 for maturity. There will be 2 for species by sex, 2 for species by maturity, and 1 for sex by maturity. By calculation or by subtraction from the overall total we can see that this leaves 2 for the three way-interaction. So R is correct in printing out just two terms for the three-way interaction. It chooses male mature leopard sharks and male mature pyjama sharks as the comment suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an anova per permutation (non-parametric) with the aovp function from lmperm package. I suggest you use perm = "exact", to have a more robust test.
For a following post hoc test you can also use pairwise.perm.t.test from RVaideMemoire package (it allows you to do a correction, and to defined the number of permutation you wish).

This is what I have used so far and it worked quite well...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, a relatively flexible method for non-parametric multi-way anova is aligned ranks transformation anova (ART anova).

At least in the implementation in R, it can handle mixed effects and has methods for post-hoc analysis.

It has its limitations, so it's important to read up on the background and documentation.