# Alternative to Friedman Test in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, friedman-test

I am trying to run a Friedman Test in `R` with a repeated measure, however, my data do not qualify as an unreplicated complete block design. I am wondering what alternative test I can run as a 3-way repeated measures ANOVA and Friedman test are not appropriate.

I am interested in knowing the interaction that soil_type, treatment, and days have on the cl_conc of my subjects. There are 48 subjects that were tested over a period of 3 days (4, 11, and 18).

Description of my data:

- `cl_conc` (response variable)
- `soil_type` (explanatory variable 1; 4 levels)
- `treatment` (explanatory variable 2; 4 levels)
- `days` (repeated measure; 3 levels)
- `core_id` (subject variable; 48 levels)

Data for reproducibility:

```
leach2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      core = c(
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "MS",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "ML",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MK",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "MC",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FS",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FL",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FK",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "FC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CK",
        "CL",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC",
        "CS",
        "CL",
        "CK",
        "CC",
        "PS",
        "PL",
        "PK",
        "PC"
      ),
      core_id = c(
        "MS1",
        "MS1",
        "MS1",
        "ML1",
        "ML1",
        "ML1",
        "MK1",
        "MK1",
        "MK1",
        "MC1",
        "MC1",
        "MC1",
        "FS1",
        "FS1",
        "FS1",
        "FL1",
        "FL1",
        "FL1",
        "FK1",
        "FK1",
        "FK1",
        "FC1",
        "FC1",
        "FC1",
        "MS2",
        "MS2",
        "MS2",
        "ML2",
        "ML2",
        "ML2",
        "MK2",
        "MK2",
        "MK2",
        "MC2",
        "MC2",
        "MC2",
        "FS2",
        "FS2",
        "FS2",
        "FL2",
        "FL2",
        "FL2",
        "FK2",
        "FK2",
        "FK2",
        "FC2",
        "FC2",
        "FC2",
        "MS3",
        "MS3",
        "MS3",
        "ML3",
        "ML3",
        "ML3",
        "MK3",
        "MK3",
        "MK3",
        "MC3",
        "MC3",
        "MC3",
        "FS3",
        "FS3",
        "FS3",
        "FL3",
        "FL3",
        "FL3",
        "FK3",
        "FK3",
        "FK3",
        "FC3",
        "FC3",
        "FC3",
        "CS1",
        "CL1",
        "CK1",
        "CC1",
        "PS1",
        "PL1",
        "PK1",
        "PC1",
        "CS2",
        "CL2",
        "CK2",
        "CC2",
        "PS2",
        "PL2",
        "PK2",
        "PC2",
        "CS3",
        "CL3",
        "CK3",
        "CC3",
        "PS3",
        "PL3",
        "PK3",
        "PC3",
        "CS1",
        "CL1",
        "CK1",
        "CC1",
        "PS1",
        "PL1",
        "PK1",
        "PC1",
        "CS2",
        "CL2",
        "CK2",
        "CC2",
        "PS2",
        "PL2",
        "PK2",
        "PC2",
        "CS3",
        "CL3",
        "CK3",
        "CC3",
        "PS3",
        "PL3",
        "PK3",
        "PC3",
        "CS1",
        "CK1",
        "CL1",
        "CC1",
        "PS1",
        "PL1",
        "PK1",
        "PC1",
        "CS2",
        "CL2",
        "CK2",
        "CC2",
        "PS2",
        "PL2",
        "PK2",
        "PC2",
        "CS3",
        "CL3",
        "CK3",
        "CC3",
        "PS3",
        "PL3",
        "PK3",
        "PC3"
      ),
      soil_type = c(
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "WSL",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "NCL ",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "ESL",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH",
        "FAH"
      ),
      treatment = c(
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "KCl",
        "SM",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control",
        "Tl",
        "SM",
        "KCl",
        "Control"
      ),
      days = c(
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        11L,
        18L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        11L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L,
        18L
      ),
      cl_conc = c(
        18.1,
        18.1,
        17.4,
        77.1,
        81.4,
        66.8,
        19.4,
        22.3,
        36.9,
        1.9,
        1.2,
        0.6,
        27.8,
        28.3,
        28.3,
        107.8,
        150.3,
        94.6,
        84.8,
        53.4,
        51.9,
        9.1,
        4.25,
        1.9,
        19.8,
        20.7,
        20.5,
        102,
        56.7,
        47.4,
        33.4,
        15.3,
        19.9,
        2,
        1.2,
        0.8,
        37.1,
        39.8,
        34.8,
        81.9,
        67.5,
        56,
        41.1,
        38.3,
        30.9,
        12.4,
        6,
        3.1,
        27.8,
        27.8,
        24.9,
        79.7,
        65.5,
        55.2,
        13.5,
        20.4,
        24.7,
        1.6,
        1.2,
        0.7,
        42.7,
        40.5,
        30.1,
        121.2,
        73.6,
        38,
        53,
        38.5,
        22.3,
        4.7,
        1.9,
        0.85,
        46.5,
        52.6,
        32.9,
        2.8,
        45.1,
        1.3,
        51.2,
        2.6,
        47.59251129,
        68.3,
        38.8,
        5.4,
        34.1,
        66.7,
        23.51266468,
        0.6,
        34.2,
        55.7,
        23.8,
        5,
        42.1,
        47.9,
        44.3,
        0.8,
        56.23151874,
        81.2,
        36.1,
        1.6,
        36.3,
        48.2,
        35.6,
        1.5,
        44.8,
        80.9,
        34.66600908,
        3.1,
        33.3,
        81.5,
        20.2,
        0.4,
        40.1,
        66.8,
        24.5,
        3.6,
        39,
        68.2,
        36,
        0.303367677,
        31.1,
        23.2,
        75.7,
        0.6,
        26.2,
        45.3,
        21.3,
        0.6,
        33.76030379,
        47.5,
        20.5,
        1.1,
        28.6,
        65.9,
        18.9,
        0.2,
        30.2,
        65.5,
        23.3,
        2.7,
        23.9,
        64,
        24.7,
        0.1
      ),
      cl_load = c(
        0.058825,
        0.0543,
        0.0609,
        0.26985,
        0.26455,
        0.2171,
        0.0582,
        0.0669,
        0.119925,
        0.0057,
        0.0036,
        0.00195,
        0.09035,
        0.0849,
        0.0849,
        0.3773,
        0.4509,
        0.3311,
        0.2756,
        0.1602,
        0.1557,
        0.03185,
        0.010625,
        0.006175,
        0.06435,
        0.07245,
        0.07175,
        0.3315,
        0.19845,
        0.1659,
        0.10855,
        0.05355,
        0.064675,
        0.0065,
        0.0039,
        0.0026,
        0.1113,
        0.1393,
        0.1044,
        0.266175,
        0.185625,
        0.168,
        0.113025,
        0.105325,
        0.0927,
        0.0372,
        0.018,
        0.010075,
        0.09035,
        0.09035,
        0.0747,
        0.2391,
        0.22925,
        0.1656,
        0.0405,
        0.0663,
        0.06175,
        0.0048,
        0.0036,
        0.0021,
        0.1281,
        0.131625,
        0.097825,
        0.3939,
        0.2392,
        0.114,
        0.17225,
        0.125125,
        0.0669,
        0.015275,
        0.006175,
        0.0023375,
        0.11625,
        0.14465,
        0.0987,
        0.0084,
        0.0902,
        0.0039,
        0.1152,
        0.00715,
        0.118981278,
        0.2049,
        0.1164,
        0.0135,
        0.093775,
        0.2001,
        0.064659828,
        0.0018,
        0.0855,
        0.1671,
        0.06545,
        0.0125,
        0.094725,
        0.131725,
        0.099675,
        0.0024,
        0.177129284,
        0.2436,
        0.1083,
        0.0048,
        0.1089,
        0.15665,
        0.1068,
        0.0045,
        0.1344,
        0.2427,
        0.11266453,
        0.010075,
        0.0999,
        0.2445,
        0.0606,
        0.0012,
        0.1203,
        0.2004,
        0.0735,
        0.0126,
        0.117,
        0.2046,
        0.117,
        0.000985945,
        0.0933,
        0.0696,
        0.2268,
        0.0018,
        0.0917,
        0.15855,
        0.0639,
        0.00195,
        0.101280911,
        0.1425,
        0.0615,
        0.003025,
        0.0858,
        0.214175,
        0.0567,
        0.00065,
        0.1057,
        0.212875,
        0.075725,
        0.0081,
        0.0717,
        0.192,
        0.0741,
        3e-04
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      6L,
      7L,
      8L,
      10L,
      11L,
      12L,
      14L,
      15L,
      16L,
      18L,
      19L,
      20L,
      22L,
      23L,
      24L,
      26L,
      27L,
      28L,
      30L,
      31L,
      32L,
      34L,
      35L,
      36L,
      38L,
      39L,
      40L,
      42L,
      43L,
      44L,
      46L,
      47L,
      48L,
      50L,
      51L,
      52L,
      54L,
      55L,
      56L,
      58L,
      59L,
      60L,
      62L,
      63L,
      64L,
      66L,
      67L,
      68L,
      70L,
      71L,
      72L,
      74L,
      75L,
      76L,
      78L,
      79L,
      80L,
      82L,
      83L,
      84L,
      86L,
      87L,
      88L,
      90L,
      91L,
      92L,
      94L,
      95L,
      96L,
      121L,
      122L,
      123L,
      124L,
      125L,
      126L,
      127L,
      128L,
      129L,
      130L,
      131L,
      132L,
      133L,
      134L,
      135L,
      136L,
      137L,
      138L,
      139L,
      140L,
      141L,
      142L,
      143L,
      144L,
      145L,
      146L,
      147L,
      148L,
      149L,
      150L,
      151L,
      152L,
      153L,
      154L,
      155L,
      156L,
      157L,
      158L,
      159L,
      160L,
      161L,
      162L,
      163L,
      164L,
      165L,
      166L,
      167L,
      168L,
      169L,
      170L,
      171L,
      172L,
      173L,
      174L,
      175L,
      176L,
      177L,
      178L,
      179L,
      180L,
      181L,
      182L,
      183L,
      184L,
      185L,
      186L,
      187L,
      188L,
      189L,
      190L,
      191L,
      192L
    ),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: please, explain which differences are you interested in. Interaction, marginal effect, etc. ?

Comment: Of course, I am interested in the interaction (if any) that soil_type, treatment, and days [since application] have on cl_conc in my experiment. I don't believe I am interested in marginal effects. Hope that helps, but I can try to elaborate more if need be

Comment: See also: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577873/is-there-a-non-parametric-form-of-a-3-way-anova/610996](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577873/is-there-a-non-parametric-form-of-a-3-way-anova/610996)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tests you cited are not appropriate due to the presence of repeated measures. The common way to deal with repeated measures is via mixed-effects linear models.

I'm considering here the most general model, borrowing from one of your earlier posts.

```
> leach_lme <- lme(fixed = cl_conc ~ soil_type*treatment*days,
+                  random =~1|core_id, data = leach2, 
+                  method = "ML")
> anova(leach_lme)
                         numDF denDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)                  1    80 677.4590  <.0001
soil_type                    3    32   6.1510  0.0020
treatment                    3    32 109.4603  <.0001
days                         1    80  17.3933  0.0001
soil_type:treatment          9    32   2.2588  0.0436
soil_type:days               3    80   3.1330  0.0301
treatment:days               3    80   1.0310  0.3834
soil_type:treatment:days     9    80   3.9676  0.0003
```

As you can see, the three-way interaction is significant, and so is the two-way interaction `soil_type:days`, etc. Linear mixed-effects is a parametric model, so as usual in the context of a linear model, one needs to check the residuals are well-behaving.

As per request in the comments, here is a quick residual check.

```
plot(leach_lme)
```

[image]

The message here is that residuals may be heteroscedastic. Now let's log-transforming the response

```
leach_lme2 <- lme(fixed = log(cl_conc) ~ soil_type*treatment*days,
                 random =~1|core_id, data = leach2, 
                 method = "ML")
plot(leach_lme2)
```

[image]

A part of a single observation which appears to be far from the bulk of the data, the residuals look fine to me, i.e. homoscedastic. The QQ-plot as well (not shown here but you can plot it yourself via `qqnorm(leach_lme2)`) doesn't seem that bad.

P.S. In this answer, I treated `days` as a numerical variable. To treat it as a factor, as you seem to be interested in (thanks Sal Mangiacifo for pointing it out), use

`leach2$days <- factor(leach2$days)`

and redo the analyses. The output will be slightly different compared to the one shown above; there will be two additional parameters to be estimated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It has been very helpful. I ran the code, and the residuals were not behaving correctly and do not get better with data transformation. It's my understanding I would need a nonparametric test, but the Friedman Test does not work on my data. I am unsure what is appropriate for this data as I have been having trouble finding a test that works for a while. Any advice for me to try going forward?

Comment: From what I can see, the residuals here are a bit heteroscedastic. here are some quick fixes that come to my mind right now: (1) Log-transform the response; I've checked and seem to fix the issue. (2) include further covariates if you have any. (3) work with the original model but compute the p-value via bootstrap; this would solve the heteroscedasticity issue.

Comment: Hi again, On my end, log transformation on the response variable does not help the model become normally distributed, and actually makes it slightly worse. I am sure I am doing something wrong on my end. I can ask it in the form of another question if you would like, but could you show me how you are fixing the data with log transformation? I would like to understand what I am doing and this is very helpful so far.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. That helped clarify the issue quite a bit. I was going solely based on a shapiro test of normality, but I see it is a little more nuanced than that. The QQ plot and this residual plot help visualize your point well.

Comment: @mbelanger081 see my updated answer. As you'll see, log-transformation does fix the heteroscedasticity issue. There is, however, a problem with a single observation having an exceptionally high residual. If this outlier bothers you, try fitting lme via a robust method; check the `robustlmm` package in R.

Comment: I would use normality tests for checking residuals with great care; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/600857/56940)

Comment: +1, although it sounds like OP wants to treat *Days* as a factor variable.  (It has only 3 levels).

Comment: @SalMangiafico agreed, though, treating `Days` as a factor would imply two additional parameters to be estimated.