# How should I treat F test if one of variances is equal 0?

Tags: f-test

I have two groups with 20 elements in each. In one group variance is equal 0. I want to do f-test. Can I? And how should I interpret results (in this case)?

Comment: Why do you want to do an F test for a group with identical values?  Also what do you want to test? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/can-i-do-a-t-test-if-i-have-little-to-no-variance-in-one-group

Comment: I wanted to compare two groups with t test and check if variance is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one group's elements are identical values (variance zero), and the other's are not, intuition says that variance is not the same. There is no need for a test.

The [F-test for variances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances) takes the ratio of the sample variances:
$$ F = \frac{S_X^2}{S_Y^2}$$
So you see that if $Y$ is the one group with the identical values (low variance) it is not defined and if $X$ (zero=low variance) it is zero (test failure). So, by definition, the larger variance should be placed in the numerator. Hence, you get an F-statistic of infinity and you can claim that the variances are different.

Comment: It's not just intuition that says that. :-) To get a sample with zero variance if the population variance is non-zero is infinitely improbable.

Comment: I think I rushed too much to answer the question. What if the population is like: $0,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,0,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,2,1,1$ and we just get a sample of 5 observations? It's highly probable to get 5 observations of just $1$.

Comment: Ok, I assumed a continuous distribution.