# How to report permutation ANOVA results in a scientific publication?

Tags: r, anova, permutation-test, reporting

I have been using `lmp` function from [lmPerm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmPerm/index.html) package to calculate differences between treatment levels (2-ANOVA). Now, I am wondering how to report `lmp` results in a scientific publication?

I am aiming for a biological or geochemical journal, but have been using [APA style](http://osil.psy.ua.edu/~Rosanna/PY602/Writing%20up%20your%20results%20%E2%80%93%20APA%20Style%20guidelines.pdf) in reporting statistics previously. I am not sure whether this is the desired way either, but at least their rules seem well defined.

Comment: As you can see in [this answer to my question here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29106/442), `lmPerm` is perhaps not to be trusted. Results may be not correct. I recommend you use `coin` instead.

Comment: @Henrik. Thanks for your comment. Hmmm...I do not experience jumping p values with my dataset. Actually I get almost the same p values than with `lm` function, although factors seem to be heteroskedastic to some degree.

Comment: Do you mean `lmp` in place of `lm` (because the latter defaults to treatment contrasts, not Tukey HSD).

Comment: @chl I am not sure what I mean. I edited the question.