# How to show the significance of the difference in means in a paired test

Tags: inference

Suppose I perform a paired test. The null hypothesis is that mean of difference is zero: $\mathrm{E[X-Y]} = 0$. The actual difference is positive but distributed *non normally*.

[image: Q-Q plot of difference mean]

Which statistical methods should I use to make a strong inference about statistical significance of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wilcoxon signed-rank test is a common alternative to the paired T-test for non-normal distributions.  If you have Mathematica 8 or above, try using the function LocationTest; otherwise it's pretty easy to roll your own from the information provided in the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with strongly non-normal data, a good option is a non-parametric permutation test. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/which-permutation-test-implementation-in-r-to-use-instead-of-t-tests-paired-and) discusses some options for permutation tests in R; I don't know what software you're using, but it may contain an option for such a test. There are a number of varieties using the mean, median (which may be more appropriate in your case, since your data seems to have heavy tails), or a test statistic of some kind.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica. There should be something useful, I guess. Thanks for the reply.