# What to do when comparing mean of two populations and one is not normal?

Tags: r, t-test, mean, normality-assumption

I have a dataset with two populations (unpaired). First one with 36 observations, second one 74.
The first passes the Shapiro normality test with `p-value = 0.1521`, the second fails it with `p-value = 0.01551`.

I would like to perform a test `t.test(first, second)`, how can I do? If I transform with a BoxCox the second population it doesn't make any more sense to compare it with the first population.

Edit:
Here is the data asked by @BruceET

```
> lapply(g, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), var=var(x), sd=sd(x)))
$mark
     mean       var        sd 
21.986111  6.364087  2.522714 

> lapply(p, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), var=var(x), sd=sd(x)))
$mark
     mean       var        sd 
25.378378  7.608293  2.758313
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: These tests of Normality are essentially irrelevant.  It's unlikely you have a problem--but the best way to assess that begins by plotting the data distribution and not by reporting the p-value of a Normality test.

Comment: Can you show means, variances, boxplots of the two samples?

Comment: @BruceET I have added what you asked for

Comment: See also:  [This CrossValidated link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/which-permutation-test-implementation-in-r-to-use-instead-of-t-tests-paired-and); the answer by Caracol for implementing a permutation test in R, and note the first comment by whuber under Caracol's answer regarding the applicability of a traditional t-test for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to digitize your data (approximately), based on your histograms. Of course, my two samples do not exactly match yours,
but they seem sufficiently similar to your data to use for illustrative purposes:

```
x1
 [1] 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21
[26] 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 27
length(x1); mean(x1); sd(x1)
[1] 50
[1] 21.12
[1] 2.115444

x2
 [1] 19 19 19 19 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23
[26] 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26
[51] 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 27 27 27 27 27 27 28 28 28 28 28 28 29 29 29 29
length(x2); mean(x2); sd(x2)
[1] 74
[1] 24.41892
[1] 2.668983
```

Normal quantile-quantile plots of both samples (`x1` at left) are roughly
linear, suggesting that neither sample is far from normally distributed.

[image]

Also, boxplots show no outliers or extreme skewness. So a pooled t test seems a reasonable choice. Notches in the
sides of the boxes are nonparametric CIs calibrated to that
lack of overlap suggests difference in medians. We should not be surprised if means are also significantly different.

[image]

A pooled 2-sample t test finds a highly significant difference
in the two sample means--with t statistic $T = -7.32$ and P-value
very near $0.$

```
t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
 t = -7.3204, df = 122, p-value = 2.896e-11
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.191024 -2.406814
sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
  21.12000  24.41892
```

We get the same results in 'stacked format':

```
x = c(x1, x2);  g = rep(1:2, c(50,74))
t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T)$stat
        t 
-7.320372
```

As in the discussion in Comments, it seems to me that a t test
is appropriate. However, if some qualms about using a t test remain in spite of the usual favorable indications, we could use the pooled t statistic as
the metric in a **permutation test.**

Whether the t statistic has
exactly Student's t distribution with 122 degrees of freedom or not,
this statistic seems a reasonable way to express the difference
between sample means, compared with the variability of the samples.

Below we use R to approximate the permutation distribution of the pooled t statistic. We scramble the $n_1 + n_2 = 124$ observations
between groups 1 and 2 repeatedly and find the t statistic for
each permutation. The resulting values of $T$ form the permutation distribution of the t statistic. Here, the P-value of the approximate permutation test is essentially $0.$
[In fact, the approximate permutation distribution of the t statistic is approximately $\mathsf{T}(\nu=122),$ shown in
the figure below.]

```
set.seed(2022)
t = replicate(10^4, t.test(x~sample(g), var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t)>=7.32)
[1] 0        # P-value of aprox permutation test.
```

[image]

*Note:* Also, the implementation of the 2-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test in R gives a reasonable P-value to indicate a change in location between samples `x1` and `x2`. [There are many ties, but the sample sizes are large enough to get a reliable P-value.

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 642.5, p-value = 6.301e-10
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I will dig deep into the argument!

Answer (score 0):

If normality is heavily violated, you can consider non-parametric methods that do not make assumptions about population distributions. Usually, there is a non-parametric equivalent to common problems like the two-sample t-test where the two samples are independent. In this case, you can use a very general Mann-Whitney test.